# Print array recursively, producing strange output

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program which takes input from a .txt file, stores the words in an array of char pointers, averages the word length and prints out any words which exceed the average length. Right now I am trying to get a print function working (print_array), I want to do this recursively. For some reason the print function is not printing out all elements of the array, it is only printing the first element and removing the first character each time. What am I doing wrong here? Cheers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAYLEN 100
#define CHARLEN 79

void *emalloc(size_t s) {
    void *result = malloc(s);
    if (NULL == result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return result;
}

void print_array(char *a, int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", &a[0]);
        print_array(a + 1, n - 1);
    }
}


int main(void) {
    char word[CHARLEN];
    char *wordlist[ARRAYLEN];
    double average;
    int num_words;

    num_words = 0;
    average = 0.0;
    while (num_words < ARRAYLEN && 1 == scanf("%79s", word)) {
        wordlist[num_words] = emalloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof wordlist[0][0]);
        strcpy(wordlist[num_words], word);
        average += strlen(word);
        num_words++;    
    }

    average = average / num_words;

    printf("Average is %.2f\n", average);

    print_array(*wordlist, num_words);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output -

```
Average is 9.71
hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```

Comment: `char word[CHARLEN];` is 1 too small for `"%79s"`.

Comment: Also if you are using a macro `CHARLEN`, it would be better to use `"%" #CHARLEN "%s"`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument `*wordlist` is the pointer to first element of `*wordlist[]`, but you want to print a two-dimensional array! So the code must look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_char_array(char *words[], int len) {
    if (len > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", words[0]);
        print_char_array(words + 1, len - 1);
    }
}

int main (int args, char *argv[]) {
    char *words[] = {
        "hello", "print", "array", "recursively", "output"
    };
    print_char_array(words, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

My English is poor, hope the code can help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
char *wordlist[ARRAYLEN];
```

Here we have an array of C strings.

```
print_array(*wordlist, num_words);
```

Here we deference the pointer, getting the first C string in the array and passing that to `print_array`.

```
void print_array(char *a, int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", &a[0]);
        print_array(a + 1, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Here we take one C string, and if `n` isn't zero, print it (`&a[0]` is a pointer to the first element in the array, which will end up being the same as `a` itself). Then we add one to the C string pointer, so that we do the same thing starting from the second character. And so on.

SOLUTION: If you want to print an array of C strings, have the `print_array` function take the whole array, not just an individual string—i.e. have it take `char **` rather than `char *`. Then, get rid of the `&` in `print_array` and the `*` in the line that calls `print_array`.

EDIT: as pointed out by @chux, your `CHARLEN` is also too small. Make it 80 so that your strings have room for 79 characters plus the necessary null terminator.